# Ladda Not Spinnning Just Posting

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

http://jsfiddle.net/DPZgj is basically the code I'm using.  When hitting "expand-left" button it just posts but doesn't start spinning.  When I change the JavaScript code to:

```
$(function() {
$('#form-submit').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var l = Ladda.create(this);
    l.start();
    $.post("your-url", 
        { data : data },
      function(response){
        console.log(response);
      }, "json")
    .always(function() { l.stop(); });
    return false;
});
```

It spins correctly just doesn't post.  What am I missing?

Comment: I get "ReferenceError: data is not defined" in the console. Define "data" before that like "var data = {a:1};"

Comment: The Fiddle doesn't work because a form submit loads whatever the POST request returns. It should work with AJAX, but you have of course set `data` to something.

Answer (score 0):

You must bind the button with:

```
Ladda.bind('.btn.ladda-button');
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DPZgj/7/